# .Net Standard 1.0 class library in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard

I have written a tiny library which I would like to release to the public. Since [the lower the standard the wider it can be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) targeting .Net Standard 1.0 would be the best. Especially since it could be used everywhere (even in older Unity versions) and the library is basically just a collection of enums.

The only problem is it seems I can't figure out how I could create a class library project targeting .NET Standard 1.0 in Visual Studio 2019. The lowest I get is .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Do you have the .NET Core 1.0 SDK installed? IIRC, the .NET Standard 1.0 target is included in that.

Comment: Hm, i have the later .NET Core SDKs and .NET 5 installed. Let me check ...

Comment: dotnet --info > 2.2.207, 3.1.100, 5.0.202

Comment: If you want to get technical, targeting .NET Framework 2.0 and then removing the target framework attribute altogether would be the *very* best in terms of what can be consumed everywhere, since the result is essentially framework neutral -- practically everything that supports IL supports such a library, if it does not reference other framework assemblies. I'm not sure whether .NET Core will allow references like that without complaint, though, so it might be less optimal in that regard.

Comment: Manually edit the `.csproj` file to put the `TargetFramework` as `netstandard1.0`? Sounds like that's just a UI restriction maybe, than an inability to do it at all.

Comment: @jeroenMostert May a good situation for a real life "multi platform" nuget?

Comment: For practical multi-targeting I wouldn't go lower than .NET Standard 1.6, as that's the highest version .NET Core 1 supports (as well as everything that's not .NET Framework) while supporting older .NET Framework versions is better done by additionally building the library explicitly for .NET Framework (since then you can go lower than 4.5 and the client does not require tooling support for consuming Standard). A single package can include both versions.

Comment: @jeroenMostert I wrote my own interpretation (enum collection) of the ISO3166 standard. In the desire to never need to type the enum again I thought it would be a good idea to release it as nuget package. Until your last comment I though .NET Standard 1.0 would be supported everywhere...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It was specifically designed to make porting between Framework, Core and Mono easier while things were transitioning to .NET Core, but it never covered the full gamut of everything .NET, and by now it's fair to say it's itself obsolete since there will be no more versions after 2.1. Even targeting .NET Standard 1.6 is not very useful these days as very few people don't upgrade from .NET Core 1, while those who are stuck with older versions of Framework can do more with assemblies targeting Framework.

Comment: @jeroenMostert hm, I see

Comment: @MartinCostello thx for the hint. I created a .NET Standard 2.0 class library and then were able to select .NET Standard 1.0 in the properies of the csproj. It just wasn't shown as option in the create project wizard. You could write it as answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that it's just not an option in the Visual Studio user interface anymore.

It should be possible to set it manually by opening your `.csproj` file and changing the `TargetFramework` by hand:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard1.0</TargetFramework>
```